# Mount remote filesystems in userspace

Tags: ssh, filesystems, mount

I like udisksctl because

1. you don't have to specify the mountpoint.
2. you don't need superuser access.

Well, as far as I know, udisksctl is only for local block devices. So is there some tool which combines udisksctl with something like sshfs?

Comment: Why don't you just use `sshfs`?

Comment: @terdon, because we still need to specify the mountpoint.. ? And the ownership isn't clean.

Comment: I don't understand. You _always_ need to specify a mountpoint unless it's defined somewhere. You can use `fstab` with `sshfs` if you want to avoid setting it each time. As for ownership, could you explain what you mean? Ownership will always be complex if you're mounting a remote drive. Please [edit] your question and explain what features/behaviors you need from this.

Comment: No, you don't need to specify the mountpoint for udisksctl or for that matter, file managers like nautilus or dolphin. Forget the ownership issue.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I wasn't being very clear. Those are configured to automatically mount under `/media` or somewhere under `/run`. But the mountpoint is configured one way or another, you just don't need to do it as a regular user. But I still don't understand what you want. So please edit your question and describe what the expected behavior would be. When should the remote drive be mounted? You're probably looking for one or more of sshaf+fstab or autofs, but we need to understand what behavior you're expecting first.

Comment: Think of the relationship between the commands "chroot" and "sshfs". You use "chroot" for local filesystems and "sshfs" for remote devices with ssh. Both of them require you to specify the mountpoint at the time of mounting. udisksctl doesn't. However, udisksctl can only mount local filesystems and not the remote ones with ssh. Yes, you can do this with nautilus, but I was looking for a simple cli tool.

Comment: One again: please ***[edit]*** your question and describe the behavior you want. You can set the mountpoint in fstab and then use `mount foo` to mount it with sshfs. Or you can use automount and mount it as soon as you try to access the mountpoint. You can probably even have it set up to mimic udisksctl and generate random mount points. But the details will depend on what behavior you are expecting. What should trigger the mount? How do you want this to work? So please ***edit*** and clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this tool called `udevil` which is kind of promising. Along with the above, it seems to handle ftp and samba shares as well. I haven't tested it much though.